# jQuery-Collapse with link in header

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I using Daniel Stocks jQuery-Collapse with cookies,
which works great.

https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Collapse

Hi, does anyone know how I can make one
of the headers a link? So when clicked 
it links to another page also containing the menu, 
and when this page is loaded, the clicked 
menu is expanded showing the sub items.

In the example below, I need fruits to link 
to another page and to be expanded at this
page:

```
 <div class="demo">             
                <h3><a href="default2.html">Fruits</a></h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Apple</li>
                    <li>Pear</li>
                    <li>Orange</li>
                </ul>
                <h3>Vegetables</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Carrot</li>
                    <li>Tomato</li>
                    <li>Squash</li>
                </ul>
                <h3>Colors</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Green</li>
                    <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow">Yellow</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_(colour)">Orange</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another problem i'm seeing is that the plugin will ignore the h3 with the link inside it.

so you'll need to combine this with a custom show() handler.

HTML

```
<h3 id="fruits" rel="index2.html#fuits">Fruits</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Apple</li>
   <li>Pear</li>
   <li>Orange</li>
 </ul>
...
```

JS

```
$(".demo").collapse({
    head: "h3",
    group: "ul",
    show: function() {
       if($(this).prev().attr('rel')){
           // open a window with the rel value as the location.
           window.location=($(this).prev().attr('rel'));
       }
       $(this).show()
    },
    hide: function(){
       $(this).hide()
    }
});
```

Then using the method mentioned by @Andrea simply set the item you want opened in the other page to be active.

so in this example if the url was #fruits then the item we'd open on load would be the h3 with id="fruits"

To do this you can use.

```
if(window.hash){
    $("#"+window.hash).addClass('active')
```

Comment: Hey guys, thank you so much!! I finally got this working by your help, and it works like a charm! :-D :-D

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can preserve the animation part, for those <h3> with normal expand/collapse functionality. Where do I put the this.animate({...}) feature in the new code?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the `a href="default2.html#id"` an id and set it to the next `ul id="id"`

in this way with javascript you can show the correct list on loading.

---

Take a look here

http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/an9Z2/

Comment: Hi Andrea, could you explain a little more? :) I'm a bit new to jQuery, sorry.

Comment: I added an example on jsFiddle! Take a look, than you can retrieve your current path using: "window.location.pathname"