# Prevent hash to work as anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery menu which is build up by like this:

```
<h3 id='300' rel='default.aspx?PageID=300#300'>Item0</h3>
<h3 id='301' rel='default.aspx?PageID=301#301'>Item1</h3>
<h3 id='302' rel='default.aspx?PageID=302#302'>Item2</h3>
```

The problem is that it triggers anchor functionallity and makes 
the page jump/scroll down to the clicked menu point.

How can I prevent this?

Best regards.

Comment: are you trying click on these `h3`?

Comment: The HTML doesn't really help, what's your jquery generating the section in question?

Comment: By not using a hash? Sorry, but what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The links are generating a kind of a vertical accordeon menu, which is posting the ID of the current page to the next, when a top menu is clicked. I've got it working here in my previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397473/jquery-collapse-with-link-in-header 

The problem is, that it jumps down to the click top menu point because it is an anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever heard of links? They are this really awesome thing in HTML.

Anyway, once you've changed each to:

```
<h3 id='300'><a href='default.aspx?PageID=300#300'>Item0</a></h3>
```

Then just add `return false;` at the end of your click handler to override the functionality.

On the actual page, then make sure there isn't anything with ID 300. It's not a valid ID anyway, so you shouldn't have any anyway.

Comment: Hi, my problem is a continuation of my earlier problem in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10397473/jquery-collapse-with-link-in-header

Comment: The links are generating a kind of a vertical accordeon menu, which is posting the ID of the current page to the next, when a top menu is clicked. Making the top menus to links doesn't really trigger what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Does it link to another page?

Comment: Hi, it links to the same which cathes up on the querystring("PageID") and displays content depending on the PageID. The menu then activates/opens the accordeon depending on the id after the hash. (e.g. #300)

Comment: So it's a link. Use an `a` element :)!  You can't have an ID called 300, it's not valid. Use JS to get the hash, and do what you want, instead of using a #300 div.

Comment: Hi again, I see what you mean but I really can't figure out how I can use a link instead with my jQuery constallation. I have put together a simple example here just to show how it works:

http://www.vextra.dk/menutest/demo/test.html

Best regards

Comment: Just change the id on them to something like link300. If the # in the address is equal to a # on the page, it will move to that anchor.

Comment: OMG! That was the only thing i had to do!? I spent so long trying to figure it out :-) Thank you Mr.!